# Why did Tasslehoff not reveal that Raistlin is the traitor?

Tags: dragonlance

Tasslehoff saw, at the end of [The Dragons of The Autumn Twilight](https://www.amazon.in/Dragons-Autumn-Twilight-Chronicles-Dragonlance-ebook/dp/B004G606K8), that Raistlin had betrayed the Party but did not tell any of the others  afterwards of what he saw. Could any of you explain that to me?

The scene was: Fizban and Tasslehoff got separated from the party and climbed up a big chain. They reached the upper balustrade of the red dragons room. Looking down a person stepped in and told the dragon the what the party plans. The dragon said: Put down your hood. Tasslehoff and Fizban saw Raistlin.
Afterwards Tasslehoff travels with Tanis and the others down south but does not mention the incident.

If the answer includes Spoilers please mark it since I have not finished the books yet.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've read the Dragonlance Chronicles, and my memory is pretty hazy. Could you please specify if you're talking about the Chronicles, Legends, etc?

Comment: I am talking about the Chronicles

Comment: Specifically, *The Raistlin Chronicles*, not the original *Chronicles* trilogy.

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was

> Eben,

not Raistlin, who betrayed the party. You probably confuse that episode with the one in Xak Tsaroth, where Raistlin wanted to get the book of Fistandantilus at all costs and considered bargaining with a dragon. But he did not betray anyone.

> Eben died later at the end of the book.